# Scroll DOM item into view with CSS alone

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

Say I have a large list of items, only one of which has class `active`. Say I can change the `active` selection using the keyboard (press arrow down and the item below becomes active). Say the list of items is taller than the viewport, and needs to be scrolled.

Is there a CSS-only way to ensure that the `active` item is always in view?

Using JavaScript, the following code can work, but I would like to avoid calling `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()` and instead tell CSS to do it for me (if possible)

```
const prevNode = getNode(/* implementation details */)
const nextNode = getNode(/* implementation details */)
prevNode.classList.remove('active')
nextNode.classList.add('active')
nextNode.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
```

This odd requirement comes because I am using React and it is weird to imperatively call `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`, when the classes are in fact added declaratively (redux state changes).

Any suggestions are much appreciated. If no nice CSS way exists, I am open to suggestions of how is best (i.e. most performant) to implement this in React if I have a long list.

Thank you!

Comment: How about focusing the active item?

Comment: by adding `autoFocus={true}`?

Comment: Not sure it would work once the element is already in the DOM. I meant it more like another suggestion with JS that has more support than scrollIntoViewIfNeeded

Answer (score 0):

Is it imperative that the window is scrolled to the active element, or is enough for the active element to just be in view? Also does ordering of these elements matter?

If all you need is for the active one to be in view you can use `display: flex;` on the list's container and make use of the `order` attribute to ensure the "active" element is always first:

```
.list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-item{
  order: 2;
}

.list-item.active {
  order: 1;
}
```

The "active" item will move to the top. When you make a different item active the previous item will move back to its natural position in the list and the new active item will move to the top.

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/vyq9h6ep/

Comment: This is really neat, but the order is important. Otherwise, this is a really cool trick.